# Unable to use external java JAR library into mulesoft datawave

Tags: java, maven, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to use a java library on my mule application.
Following [this](https://mulesy.com/external-jar-class-in-dataweave/) tutorial, i successfully imported and invoked the extended StringUtils class in Datawave. But when i do the same for my own library, it fails.

Here the steps o followed from the tutorial:

1. Add the dependency to my `mylib` artifact:

   ```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. configure the maven plugin to use the shared lib:

   ```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>

      <configuration>
        <sharedLibraries>
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>com.example.shared</groupId>
                <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
            </sharedLibrary>
        </sharedLibraries>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Add the package `com.example.shared` to the class loader:

   ```
    {
      "minMuleVersion": "4.4.0",
      "classLoaderModelLoaderDescriptor": {
            "id": "mule",
            "attributes": {
                "exportedPackages": [           
                 "com.example.shared"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Yet, when i try to call it from `Datawave`, in the same way presented by the tutorial:

```
    example: java!com::example::shared::MyUtils::foo()
```

i get:

```
   Unable to resolve reference of: `com::example::shared::MyUtils::foo`. at 7 : 7" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
```

Note: The `Anypoint Studio` shows an error in the `Datawave` preview window but it builds and runs successfully.
The same kind of error is present when using `StringUtills` from `common-lang3` library, that is used on the tutorial example.

Update:
Here is the java code:

```
package com.example.shared;

public class MyUtils {

    public static String foo() {
        return "I'm here.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the source for the Java function you are trying to use.

Comment: Just added MyUtills Class.